# Missing Gnome icons

Tags: 14.04, gnome, icons, ubuntu-gnome

The current problem has happened to me for the second time (last time I reinstalled whole Ubuntu to solve it)
I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome
I have done some updates using the Software Updater, and I have lost several icons in the applications menu (if I change the theme using Tweak Tool, I get them back, but in every restart some icons are disappearing again).

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

The update affected these packages:

```
Start-Date: 2015-03-01  17:21:45
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.264'
Install: libllvm3.6:amd64 (3.6~+rc2-2ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1)
Upgrade: e2fslibs:amd64 (1.42.9-3ubuntu1, 1.42.9-3ubuntu1.2), xserver-xorg-video-vmware:amd64 (13.0.2-2ubuntu1, 13.0.2+git20140804.0a596fd0-0ubuntu0sarvatt~trusty), intel-gpu-tools:amd64 (1.3-0ubuntu2.1, 1.8-1~xedgers~trusty), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3, 10.5.0~git20150204.661c8bb2-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), multiarch-support:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.5, 2.19-0ubuntu6.6), cups-core-drivers:amd64 (1.7.2-0ubuntu1.2, 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.5), cups-server-common:amd64 (1.7.2-0ubuntu1.2, 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.5), libopenvg1-mesa:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3, 10.4.0~git20141112.7a82961b-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), python-samba:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.5, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7), e2fsprogs:amd64 (1.42.9-3ubuntu1, 1.42.9-3ubuntu1.2), libegl1-mesa-drivers:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3, 10.5.0~git20150204.661c8bb2-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), firefox-locale-en:amd64 (35.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 36.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.4), xserver-xorg-video-sisusb:amd64 (0.9.6-2build1, 0.9.6+git20140806.293d0902-0ubuntu0sarvatt~trusty), nvidia-settings:amd64 (346.35-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1, 346.47-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1), libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.56-1~ubuntu2, 2.4.59+git20150225.1f73578d-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl:amd64 (0.6.0-0ubuntu4, 0.6.0+git20140801.347ef4f0-0ubuntu0sarvatt~trusty), libllvm3.4:amd64 (3.4-1ubuntu3, 3.4.2-3ubuntu2~xedgers), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3, 10.5.0~git20150204.661c8bb2-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), xserver-xorg-video-neomagic:amd64 (1.2.8-1build1, 1.2.8+git20140806.74a9a343-0ubuntu0sarvatt~trusty), libcups2:amd64 (1.7.2-0ubuntu1.2, 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.5), cups-daemon:amd64 (1.7.2-0ubuntu1.2, 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.5), libcomerr2:amd64 (1.42.9-3ubuntu1, 1.42.9-3ubuntu1.2), firefox:amd64 (35.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 36.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.4), libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.56-1~ubuntu2, 2.4.59+git20150225.1f73578d-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), libfreetype6:amd64 (2.5.2-1ubuntu2.3, 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.4), libcupsmime1:amd64 (1.7.2-0ubuntu1.2, 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.5), cups-client:amd64 (1.7.2-0ubuntu1.2, 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.5), libwayland-server0:amd64 (1.4.0-1ubuntu1, 1.7.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1), libc-dev-bin:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.5, 2.19-0ubuntu6.6), libcupsimage2:amd64 (1.7.2-0ubuntu1.2, 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.5), libc-bin:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.5, 2.19-0ubuntu6.6), libc6:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.5, 2.19-0ubuntu6.6), libss2:amd64 (1.42.9-3ubuntu1, 1.42.9-3ubuntu1.2), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3, 10.5.0~git20150204.661c8bb2-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), cups:amd64 (1.7.2-0ubuntu1.2, 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.5), libwayland-cursor0:amd64 (1.4.0-1ubuntu1, 1.7.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1), samba-common-bin:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.5, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3, 10.5.0~git20150204.661c8bb2-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), libxatracker2:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3, 10.5.0~git20150204.661c8bb2-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), language-pack-gnome-en:amd64 (14.04+20141110, 14.04+20150219), cups-bsd:amd64 (1.7.2-0ubuntu1.2, 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.5), xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 (2.99.910-0ubuntu1.4, 2.99.917+git20150225.2b978c71-0ubuntu0sarvatt~trusty), samba-libs:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.5, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7), xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 (7.3.0-1ubuntu3.1, 7.4.99+git20140806.fbf575cb-0ubuntu0sarvatt~trusty), libglamor0:amd64 (0.6.0-0ubuntu4, 0.6.0+git20140801.347ef4f0-0ubuntu0sarvatt~trusty), ca-certificates:amd64 (20130906ubuntu2, 20141019ubuntu0.14.04.1), libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.56-1~ubuntu2, 2.4.59+git20150225.1f73578d-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), libcupscgi1:amd64 (1.7.2-0ubuntu1.2, 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.5), libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3, 10.5.0~git20150204.661c8bb2-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), libwayland-client0:amd64 (1.4.0-1ubuntu1, 1.7.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1), xserver-xorg-video-trident:amd64 (1.3.6-0ubuntu5, 1.3.6+git20140806.562c38ca-0ubuntu0sarvatt~trusty), smbclient:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.5, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7), libgbm1:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3, 10.5.0~git20150204.661c8bb2-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), libcupsppdc1:amd64 (1.7.2-0ubuntu1.2, 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.5), libc6-i386:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.5, 2.19-0ubuntu6.6), cups-common:amd64 (1.7.2-0ubuntu1.2, 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.5), xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64 (7.3.0-1ubuntu3.1, 7.4.99+git20140806.fbf575cb-0ubuntu0sarvatt~trusty), language-pack-en-base:amd64 (14.04+20140707, 14.04+20150219), language-pack-gnome-en-base:amd64 (14.04+20140707, 14.04+20150219), libwbclient0:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.5, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7), cups-ppdc:amd64 (1.7.2-0ubuntu1.2, 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.5), libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.5, 2.19-0ubuntu6.6), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-45.74, 3.13.0-46.76), samba-common:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.5, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7), libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.56-1~ubuntu2, 2.4.59+git20150225.1f73578d-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), language-pack-en:amd64 (14.04+20141110, 14.04+20150219), unattended-upgrades:amd64 (0.82.1ubuntu2, 0.82.1ubuntu2.1), libc6-dev:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.5, 2.19-0ubuntu6.6), libsmbclient:amd64 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.5, 4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7), xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 (1.0.10-1ubuntu2, 1.0.11+git20141030.3fb97d78-0ubuntu0sarvatt~trusty2)
End-Date: 2015-03-01  17:23:55
```

Any idea what it might be the problem?

Comment: NEVER provide additional information as an answer! Answers are only existing for answering questions. To add something to any kind of your posts, [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/591527/edit) it. You find the same small grey link directly below your posts. I did it for you this time, as you are a newbie on AskUbuntu (Welcome, by the way!), but this is not our job, as it steals our time in which we could also write answers. The other possibility (usually less recommended) is to leave a _comment_ on your post, but whenever you add details or command outputs, better edit the question. Thank you!

Comment: A quick look how Ask Ubuntu works, see [About]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I fixed it with by running these:

`sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade`

the upgrade did the real work. also check this out if you worry about running "upgrade"
[What is the difference between apt-get update and upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94102/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-update-and-upgrade)