# What causes Pinta to crash instantly when I begin image selection?

Tags: 17.04, crash, pinta

I make a selection of a part of an image because I want to crop it, and Pinta immediately crashes. I removed Pinta with `purge` and reinstalled, but the problem persists.

The error message is:

> Pinta.exe assert failure: ***Error in usr/bin/mono: double free or 
>   corruption (out): 0x000005579etc.***

In the `UnreportableReason` section of the error message I'm told that I have some obsolete package versions installed (*libgssapi-krb-5-2*, *libk5crypto3*, *libkrb5-3*, *libkrb5support0*, *libssl1.0.0*).

Upgraded, restarted, but I still get the crashes.

I use Ubuntu 17.04.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you do both `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: No, I only did `upgrade`. Should I have run `update` as well?

Comment: Fairly new with Ubuntu, I [see](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94102/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-update-and-upgrade#94104) that `update` should preceed  `upgrade`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes., `sudo apt update` updates the local database over available packages and versions thereof. `sudo apt upgrade` does the actual upgrade of your system's installed software.

Comment: To all who will eventually read this, I installed [Shutter](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter/) as a replacement for Pinta. After one day of use, I can tell it's much much better, having much more functionality.

Comment: Actually, Shutter isn't more featureful than Pinta, and the two are really for different purposes. Shutter is a screenshot tool with a built in editor, Pinta is a dedicated editor. If you are experiencing crashes, check here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: Yes, you're right, I managed to see that as I've been using Shutter for a couple of months now. I still use Pinta sometimes to resize the resolution of certain images, so I definitely agree with the purpose you mentioned for each of these two apps.

Comment: Problem persists in Bionic Beaver

Answer (score 31):

Probably it's Mono problem and seemly v4.4.1 or older or dependently in some versions only.

Try once install/keep up-to-date the Mono by the following command (Ubuntu 18.04):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mono-devel
```

Or in older Ubuntu please follow [instructions mentioned here](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-Lin).

Sometimes [installing mono-runtime package](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/base/mono-runtime) would be enough to fix that.

You may also need to follow 3<sup>rd</sup> step in instructions and do [**Installation Verification**](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/).

If Mono was working fine then you should not have crash problems when using crop in Pinta as well.

You may need to try with [different versions of Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/) to get it to work.

Comment: Okay, this *did* fix the problem apparently. seems the crash (which I mentioned in my now deleted comment) was unrelated.

Comment: At least you need to tell us in which version of Mono on Ubuntu 17.04 you get this fixed :  )

Comment: What-ever came with that PPA (mono-devel is the package I installed but I didn't check the version, lol). Unfortunately, it seems not to have solved every issue. Certain actions are still producing an instantaneous crash, but there's nothing we can do - the developer hasn't had time to work on it (Pinta) in a while and no one else has stepped up. Maybe I can provide more details later (I should be sleeping).

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65756/discussion-on-answer-by-s-what-causes-pinta-to-crash-instantly-when-i-begin).

Comment: Latest mono didn't work for me on 17.04. Any alternatives to pinta?

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18. Official upgrade instructions are here: https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin

Comment: Doesnt work on ubuntu 18.04 . Try xpaint instead and save 30 minutes

Comment: The best alternative if you want drawing features KolourPaint https://kde.org/applications/graphics/org.kde.kolourpaint , in the second position a new cool app MyPaint http://mypaint.org/downloads/

Answer (score 11):

Seems that default Ubuntu package of Pinta is 1.6 (check version with $ pinta --version). In Pinta 2.0 this issue is resolved, but you should try to install new version via snap:

```
sudo apt purge pinta
sudo snap install pinta
```

Big thanks for this answer:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/pinta/+bug/1786822/comments/21

Comment: This did it for me.

Comment: Glad it helps, I spent so much time to figure it out

Comment: Should be the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

It is a known bug

Pinta constantly crashes in Ubuntu 18.04 fresh install

https://bugs.launchpad.net/pinta/+bug/1786822

Installing Mono MAY help (not guaranteed)

https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin

It seems like certain actions - for example drawing a selection box, clicking somewhere, then leaving Pinta for a bit, is a workaround for it not to crash. Not consistent enough to say with certainty.