# What does the apt-key adv command mean?

Tags: apt, keyserver

I just read [αғsнιη's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/955564) on [What causes Pinta to crash instantly when I begin image selection?](https://askubuntu.com/q/926458)

But what does the first line of the solution mean?

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
```

I have never encountered this command before. Is it safe to use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`apt-key`'s manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-key.8.html) explains this well.

> **adv**
>    Pass advanced options to gpg. With **`adv --recv-key`** you can e.g.
>    download key from keyservers directly into the trusted set of keys.
>    Note that there are **no** checks performed, so it is easy to
>    completely undermine the [**apt-secure**(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-secure.8.html) infrastructure if used
>    without care.

You're actually telling `apt-key` to receive `3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF` key from [keyserver.ubuntu.com](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com) and add that to trusted set of keys.

One should add key using advance options with `apt-key` only if the keyserver is trusted since the system assume that the user themselves trust the keyserver.

Comment: Ah ok thanks a lot guess .ubuntu.com is trustworthy. How can I figure out the key of the server? Is it a ssh public key?

Comment: @newandlost The key is fetched from server using HTTP Keyserver Protocol (HKP).