# Why does Pinta crash immediately after opening an image on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, mono, pinta

When opening pinta on the command line the app quickly crashes after opening an image and complains about a call to `free()` erroring out before doing a full memory dump.

Comment: @guiverc done thanks for letting me know about that

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [What causes Pinta to crash instantly when I begin image selection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926458/what-causes-pinta-to-crash-instantly-when-i-begin-image-selection)

It looks like there's another mono configuration issue in the ubuntu 20 image.

The fix is to upgrade `mono` to the latest:

```
sudo apt install gnupg ca-certificates
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
sudo apt update
```

You can do `mono --version` to see if this bug affects you or not. I believe the version that ships with Ubuntu 20 is around `6.8.0.105` from memory. After upgrading you'll see `6.12.0.122` or something similar.

Sources:

1. https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin
2. https://bugs.launchpad.net/pinta/+bug/1877235

Comment: The `apt` commands cannot be used to 20 products, as they are *snap* only and *snap install* adds packages.  Deb packages and thus `apt` and `dpkg` commands apply only to *year.month* format products.

Comment: looks like I was a little too lazy with the name - meant 20.04 LTS

Comment: So don'mt be lazy now and edit the question and answer accordingly.

Comment: The title was updated...