# difference between apt update and apt-get update

Tags: apt

I am new to Ubuntu and I found that there

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade          #1
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade  #2
```

what is the difference between them, I haven't found much information about the first command but plenty of explanation on [What is the difference between apt-get update and upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94102/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-update-and-upgrade)

Comment: Also `apt update` shows the number of upgradeable packages (if any).

Comment: `apt` is newer with some nice *shiny* features that does most of what much older `apt-get` does; but can't do everything, thus `apt-get` is still required for some less used functions.