# Cannot update Kubuntu after migration from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: apt, updates, kubuntu

Few days ago I successfully upgraded the Kubuntu from 19.04 to 19.10. After migration to new version, I cannot find any app which allows to download and install new updates. Before migration everything worked fine, now system tray (Status and notifications)does not show update app.

What can I do to fix it?

"sudo apt update" returns more than 750 packages that can be updated but nothing is installed.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between apt-get update and upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/q/94102)

Comment: Just after an upgrade to 19.10, I would expect the system to be completely up-to-date and not require more updates for a while?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between apt-get update and upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94102/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-update-and-upgrade)

Comment: well.... few days behind me and system still not install any new updates. I can do this manually, usin Terminal. Which app may I use to force system to check updates automatically and show me the results as it was in the previous version of Kubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt update` merely refreshes apt's package database.

To actually install upgrades, you must follow with `sudo apt upgrade`.