# What does this mean: sudo apt -update?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu

What is the meaning of (sudo)?.I looked for the meaning, but I could not find it.

Comment: [Here’s a Wiki link that explains `sudo` and it’s history](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) rather well. It’s better than being signed in as root all the time 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `sudo` is used to execute commands that require root permissions as a non-root user.

`sudo apt -update` or I assume you mean `sudo apt update`, [updates available upgrades](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94102/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-update-and-upgrade), which can be upgraded with `sudo apt upgrade`